# SQL Server 2014: Add space after comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to update only the values in `Column1` that have characters of a string, then a comma, then (without a space) more characters, like so: `abc,def` or `abc,123,def`. I want a space to be added between the comma and the next character, like so: `abc, def` or `abc, 123, def`. It shouldn't add an extra space if there already is one.

Sorry, I don't have any existing SQL to show-- I'm not sure where to even start on this.

Comment: Take the reverse approach. Remove all spaces after the comma and then add one space back after each comma.

Comment: You can use `REPLACE(Column1, ', ', ',')` and then `REPLACE(Column1, ',', ', ')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd first replace all instances of `,` (comma + space) with `,` (comma, NO space). That way everything is uniform. Then go the other way; replace commas with comma + space

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a little overkill, but this will support any combination of space(s) before and after a comma

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'abc  ,     123 , def,    ddd'

Select replace(replace(replace(replace(@S,',','<>'),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',', ')
```

**Returns**

```
abc, 123, def, ddd
```

---

**I should add**, this is a little trick from Gordon several months ago.  I don't have the original link

Answer (score 0):

I think you are need to first remove space and then add space to column1 near

```
 UPDATE yt set yt.Column1 =replace(replace(yt.Column1 ,' ',''),',',', ')
  from yourtable yt
  where yt.Column1 like '%,%'
```

Comment: FYI, this SQL would result in comma+space turning into comma+space+space

Comment: This will convert ', ' into ',  '.

Comment: But he is want 'commaspace ' instead of 'comma'

Answer (score 0):

This would do what you are wanting

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET Col1 = REPLACE(REPLACE(Col1,', ',','),',',', ')
WHERE Col1 LIKE '%,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If one needs exactly one space after the comma and the data is not consistent there is also the option of a string_split and then string_agg:

```
DECLARE @test varchar(max) = 'Test, Test 12,Test34,Test56 ,     Test78'
select STRING_AGG(Trim(value),', ') as Test from string_split(@test,',')
```

Result:

```
Test, Test 12, Test34, Test56, Test78
```

If possible you should use the new "enable_ordinal" option of string_split, but i actually never had problems with the order.